# SoapUI 5.6.0 UnsupportedClassVersionError on Windows 8.1

Tags: soapui, windows-8.1, java-15

I have installed following version of Java on Windows 8.1. `JAVA_HOME` environment variable points to newly installed JDK library.

```
java 15 2020-09-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I've started SoapUI 5.6, I have got following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/eviware/soapui/SoapUI has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:81)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
```

Comment: SoapUI normally comes packaged with its own Java. Remove your JAVA_HOME and try starting SoapUI again.

Comment: @SiKing : Another application uses the variable, so I can't remove it.

Comment: Is it possible to just **try it**?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Getting-the-following-error-while-opening-SoapUI-5-6/td-p/204940) link for a fix, which is a diffeent Java version.

The [requirements](https://www.soapui.org/open-source/system-requirements/) say Java 7, in fact Java 8 is recommended in more than one [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385909/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-in-soapui).

But yes, I think the error

```
com/eviware/soapui/SoapUI has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

is misleading regarding major java versions. Someone with a better grasp of Java versions may be able to explain.

Comment: I downloaded Java version from these URLs, that are mentioned on SmartBear forum article. It isn't working on that way.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error ? Perhaps use SoapUI 5.5

Comment: Yes, but I would like to try out the new version.

Comment: Log an issue with them. https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/issues

Comment: Sir, you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 1):

This is just a workaround.

Go to the installation directory (e.g C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.6.0\bin)
and launch soapui (Windows batch file) instead of SoapUI-5.6.0 (Application).

This works fine.